# Differences in passing a function to state with and without a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was learning about React's Context and the material I was looking at basically used a constructor, I tried to get fancy and see if I could do it without a constructor and here's what I came up with which works. But during the process I realized that I don't have a solid understanding of several key concepts and the working code is basically just a result of trial and error!

Here's what I do know:

- There's no need to use `bind(this)` on `toggleName` in the constructor because it's setup using an arrow function.

Here's what I need explained:

- Why does the constructor use a function reference but the no constructor state setup uses a function call?
- Why does the no constructor state setup require an additional arrow function along with the function call?

**I understand I've setup state twice in the App component, this is to show the two different approaches.**

The provider component:

```js
const UserData = React.createContext();

class App extends Component {

  // classic approach
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: 'Rick',
      toggleName: this.toggleName
    };
  }

   // alternate approach
   state = {
     name: 'Rick',
     toggleName: () => this.toggleName()
   };

  toggleName = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      name: state.name === 'Rick' ? 'Morty' : 'Rick'
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <UserData.Provider value={this.state}>
        {/* ... rest of code */}
      </UserData.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And the consumer component:

```js
const ConsumerComponent = () => (
  <UserData.Consumer>
    {({ name, toggleName }) => (
      <div onClick={toggleName}>
        {name}
      </div>
    )}
  </UserData.Consumer>
);
```

Comment: does your alternative approach need the wrapping function? I'm pretty sure it would work if you just did `state = { toggleName: this.toggleName }` since you are indeed using an arrow function

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you wanna have your method on state?

Comment: @azium that's what I thought at first but when I inspect the state (chrome React extension) the toggleName disappears without any errors, I'm not sure what's happening! It has something to do with it not understanding what 'this' is because as soon as I put `state = { toggleName: 'this.toggleName' }` meaning put function ref in single quotes and make it a string the toggleName reappears in state!

Comment: @ChaimFriedman this is a good question so yes I could alternatively do `<UserData.Provider value={{name: this.state.name, toggleName: this.toggleName}}>` but the material I was looking at was putting it in state so I did the same, that's besides the point because all these methods work and I still don't have a full understanding of why they work the way they do :)

Comment: oh I totally get that this is not the point of your question, but I never saw that before so I figured I would ask

Comment: @ChaimFriedman no worries, I forgot to mention that [Facebook docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats) discourage creating an object on the fly inside the Provider like so, therefore passing the state object is best. This is because you don't want all child consumer components to re-render with the parent every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you need the wrapping function in the "alternative" approach is because you are trying to reference something that hasn't been initialized yet. This is one of the ways that class "properties" differs from class "methods", which will already be attached to the class reference by the time the constructor runs. Simply changing the order of your statements makes it work:

```
class App extends Component {
  toggleName = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      name: state.name === 'Rick' ? 'Morty' : 'Rick'
    }));
  };

   // alternate approach
   state = {
     name: 'Rick',
     toggleName: this.toggleName // now it is initialized
   };


  render() {
    return (
      <UserData.Provider value={this.state}>
        {/* ... rest of code */}
      </UserData.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-murdock-5588y)